# using _.memoize() with _.debounce()

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'd like to debounce the render function for each call to a specific page - rendering a different page would debounce separately. The memoize function should do the trick, but it's not working correctly.

```
var renderPage_underscore = function(pageNo){
  var debouncer = _.memoize(
    // memoize function
    _.debounce(
      // debounced function
      function () {
        // Do renderPage() work here
        document.getElementById("underscore").innerHTML += 
            '<br />' + pageNo + '@' +   new Date().getTime();
      },
      1000, // delay
      true
    ),
    // memoize hash function
    function (pageNo) {
        return pageNo;
    }
  );
  return debouncer(pageNo);
};
```

any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/Zq8Wd/1/

Comment: What's "not working correctly"?  What does this code do compared to what you want it to do?

Comment: the alt version debounces correctly, the memoized version passes every call through. it should wait 1000ms before allowing the subsequent call to render the same page

Comment: Just wrote gist for memoized async debounced function based on arg, could be useful
https://gist.github.com/nzvtrk/1a444cdf6a86a5a6e6d6a34f0db19065

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with using `_.memoize()` this way is that it caches return values, not side-effects.  If you wanted to use `_.memoize()` for this problem, you'd probably have to do something like this:

```
rp = _.memoize(function (pageNo) {
    return _.debounce(function () {
        document.getElementById("underscore").innerHTML +=
            '<br />' + pageNo + '@' + new Date().getTime();
    }, 1000, true);
});

rp(1)();
rp(2)();
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zq8Wd/3/).

Comment: that's precisely what I don't understand. I see that your version works correctly, but passes pageNo in as a closure variable. But in my version, _.debounce() returns a function which I wanted memoize to cache. I'm not sure what the side-effects are.  

whats the difference between _.memoize(function(){_return _.debounce()}) and function(){return (_.memoize(_.debounce()))()})

Comment: You're right--I didn't word my answer very well :)  Maybe this will help: in your example, every time `renderPage_underscore()` is called, a function will be memoized and executed.  I think you want to memoize just once?

Comment: Question: For API compaitbility, is there a way to execute the memoized fn immediately, ie instead of rp(1)() the call is rp(1)?

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with this:

```
/**
 * Memoizes and debounces a function. i.e., returns a new function, that when invoked,
 * returns a Promise that will resolve after `delay` ms unless invoked repeatedly,
 * in which case the last promise will be rejected and the delay will be reset. If the 
 * result has already been computed, will resolve instantly.
 * 
 * @param {Function} func Function to memoize+debounce
 * @param {Number} delay Delay in milliseconds
 * @param {Function} serialize Function used to resolve the cache key
 * @return {Function} Memoized+debounced function.
 */
function membounce(func, delay=333, serialize = x => x) {
    let cache = new Map();
    let timer, cancel, lastKey;
    return (...args) => {
        let key = serialize.call(func, ...args);
        if(timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            cancel(new Error('Debounced'));
            cache.delete(lastKey);
        }
        if(cache.has(key)) {
            return cache.get(key);
        }
        let promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            cancel = reject;
            timer = setTimeout(() => {
                let result = func(...args);
                resolve(result);
                timer = null;
            }, delay);
        });
        cache.set(key, promise);
        lastKey = key;
        return promise;
    };
}
```

It *always* returns a `Promise` so you can just wait for it to resolve, and ignore any rejections which means the value was debounced/not computed.